# How can I make only *one* user controlled database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image: Purpose]

How can I system admin let it be me, but another users and admins must be cannot access my database.
My database located on customer server. I deleted all sql users, there's only sa user. This persons don't know my sa password. But this persons created sa similar users, and can access my database. I want block this users to my db.

Comment: Don't give anyone else login credentials?

Comment: You want to block a customer from using their own server? Good luck with that. Whoever has physical access to the hardware is god.

Comment: select * from sys.server_principals may help you understanding who get access to what (just a starting point)

Comment: Not possible. See the list of possible issues here http://www.netlib.com/sa_lockout.asp (and I notice that they only say they "try" to guard against these)

Answer (score 1):

You can only really hope to log this and raise alerts.  Users who can administer the hardware can always stop the service and bring a database up in single user mode etc.  They can give themselves elevated permissions etc.

It's a common requirement to segregate administrative duties so that server admins cannot see confidential files or confidential data.

However, because every administrative role can typically elevate their rights or create other users, requiring users to use least privilege accounts for their daily work and auditing what is done with elevated accounts is really the only way to deal with it.

Answer (score -1):

1. Ensure there are no unwanted groups like BUILT-IN\ADMINISTRATOR granted rights to the server & therefore your database, as that is a common backdoor for your windows Admin to get into your databases.
2. Explicitly deny the user access to your database

   use [PrivateDatabaseName];
   revoke connect from guest;
   revoke connect from user1;
   revoke connect from user2;

Comment: Did you even bother to test this? Of course it doesn't work and even the syntax is wrong.

Comment: I did not. My fault. I have updated the syntax.